# Duplicate terminal tab with shortcut

Tags: release-freya, pantheon-terminal

I'm using Freya 0.3.2. Is there any built in shortcut to duplicate current tab in terminal?

Comment: you mean same PWD ?

Comment: Yes, I meas the same PWD.